# Difference between referencing in javascript and babel in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am new to reactJs and was going through the [code](https://github.com/kirupa/kirupa/blob/master/react/todo.htm). I want the babel format to be converted to javascript. So, I went to the [site](https://babeljs.io/repl/) and converted JXS elements to its corresponding element in javascript for react. Now if using the javascript version of the code

```
render: function render() {
            var _this = this;

            return React.createElement("div",{ className: "todoListMain" },
              React.createElement("div",{ className: "header" },
                React.createElement(
                  "form",
                  { onSubmit: this.addItem },
                  React.createElement("input", { ref: function ref(a) {
                      return _this._inputElement = a;
                    },
                    placeholder: "enter task" }),
                  React.createElement("button",{ type: "submit" },"add"
                  )
                )
              ),
              React.createElement(TodoItems, { entries: this.state.items })
            );
          }
```

getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_inputElement' of undefined` in the browser console. But when I use the babel version of the same code which is

```
 render: function() {
        return (
          <div className="todoListMain">
            <div className="header">
              <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
                <input ref={(a) => this._inputElement = a}
                       placeholder="enter task">
                </input>
                <button type="submit">add</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <TodoItems entries={this.state.items}/>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

it is working fine. What is creating problem in javascript code which is not happening in babel version ? Is the way of referencing is wrong in javascript version or something else is wrong ?

Javascript converted code added.

```
var destination = document.querySelector("#container");

    var TodoItems = React.createClass({
      displayName: "TodoItems",

      render: function render() {
        var todoEntries = this.props.entries;

        function createTasks(item) {
          return React.createElement("li",{ key: item.key },item.text
          );
        }

        var listItems = todoEntries.map(createTasks);

        return React.createElement("ul",{ className: "theList" },listItems
        );
      }
    });

    var TodoList = React.createClass({
          displayName: "TodoList",

          getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
            return {
              items: []
            };
          },
          addItem: function addItem(e) {
            var itemArray = this.state.items;

            itemArray.push({
              text: this._inputElement.value,
              key: Date.now()
            });

            this.setState({
              items: itemArray
            });

            this._inputElement.value = "";

            e.preventDefault();
          },

          render: function render() {
            var _this = this;

            return React.createElement("div",{ className: "todoListMain" },
              React.createElement("div",{ className: "header" },
                React.createElement(
                  "form",
                  { onSubmit: this.addItem },
                  React.createElement("input", { ref: function ref(a) {
                      return _this._inputElement = a;
                    },
                    placeholder: "enter task" }),
                  React.createElement("button",{ type: "submit" },"add"
                  )
                )
              ),
              React.createElement(TodoItems, { entries: this.state.items })
            );
          }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("div",null,React.createElement(TodoList, null)), destination);
```

Comment: Why would you convert the code? Babel isn't a language, its simply a transpiler to convert es6, es7 javascript to be compatible with older browsers.

Comment: if you are doing this in browser post all the resources you are using. if you are using webpack post your entire configuration.

Comment: @Daniel_L have added the converted javascript code and link to code for babel is in the post. Please check and revert for any issues.

Comment: ...still don't understand why you are "converting"...

Comment: @erichardson30  wanted to use only  javascript instead of `babel`.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the steps I think you took and simply getting the page working even with the code you provide in you question. I tried to force the Error you got, and I couldn't, but I think you decoupled code, or rearranged it in a way **strict mode** just got in your way. Your error is telling us that you're trying to set a property `_inputElement` to `undefined`, `_inputElement` is only attatched to `this` in your code (or even `_this`, which is a reference to this). There are two possible ways `this` can be `undefined`:

1. Explicitly binding `undefined` to `this`. It's something like this: `doSomething.bind(undefined, arg1, arg2)`. *Update: This only works on 'strict mode', because otherwise this is always forced to be an object, it will default to global object*
2. Implicit on **Strict Mode**. `this` won't default to global object, but be given `undefined` value instead.

I think the second is applied here. If you misplaced the code, somewhat you made `this` default to `undefined` in code generated by Babel, because of `use strict` statement being added, that error won't show on the JSX code (before babel compiling) because it will default to `global` object (since it doesn't have `use strict` statement).

Anyway here you have a working version of the page with the compiled code, which is a copy and paste of the code you supplied on you own question:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>React! React! React!</title>
  <script src="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t39.3284-6/13065892_243502592679528_80343462_n.js"></script>
  <script src="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t39.3284-6/13176388_1695714220691119_811926456_n.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      padding: 50px;
      background-color: #66CCFF;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    .todoListMain .header input {
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: 2px solid #FFF;
    }
    .todoListMain .header button {
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 10px;
      background-color: #0066FF;
      color: #FFF;
      border: 2px solid #0066FF;
    }
    .todoListMain .header button:hover {
      background-color: #003399;
      border: 2px solid #003399;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .todoListMain .theList {
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 0;
      width: 255px;
    }
    .todoListMain .theList li {
      color: #333;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
      padding: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
var destination = document.querySelector("#container");

    var TodoItems = React.createClass({
      displayName: "TodoItems",

      render: function render() {
        var todoEntries = this.props.entries;

        function createTasks(item) {
          return React.createElement("li",{ key: item.key },item.text
          );
        }

        var listItems = todoEntries.map(createTasks);

        return React.createElement("ul",{ className: "theList" },listItems
        );
      }
    });

    var TodoList = React.createClass({
          displayName: "TodoList",

          getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
            return {
              items: []
            };
          },
          addItem: function addItem(e) {
            var itemArray = this.state.items;

            itemArray.push({
              text: this._inputElement.value,
              key: Date.now()
            });

            this.setState({
              items: itemArray
            });

            this._inputElement.value = "";

            e.preventDefault();
          },

          render: function render() {
            var _this = this;

            return React.createElement("div",{ className: "todoListMain" },
              React.createElement("div",{ className: "header" },
                React.createElement(
                  "form",
                  { onSubmit: this.addItem },
                  React.createElement("input", { ref: function ref(a) {
                      return _this._inputElement = a;
                    },
                    placeholder: "enter task" }),
                  React.createElement("button",{ type: "submit" },"add"
                  )
                )
              ),
              React.createElement(TodoItems, { entries: this.state.items })
            );
          }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("div",null,React.createElement(TodoList, null)), destination);

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Here you have more information on `this` and its behavior:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [You don't know JS: this object & prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)